# Relacionar dos consultas en una tabla en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, primeng

necesito juntar dos peticiones que recibo a traves de una api en una misma tabla.

La primera petición la recibo de esta forma(mostrando solo los campos que son necesarios para la tabla):

```
[
    {
      "Nombre": "Color",
      "IdProd": 134,
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Talla",
      "Id": 134,
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Revision",
      "Id": 134,
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Serial",
      "Id": 134,
    }
]
```

La segunda petición la recibo de la siguiente forma:

```
[
    {
      "IdCampo": "Serial",
      "ValorFijo": "LC0314",
    },
    {
      "IdCampo": "Revision",
      "ValorFijo": "1.7.3",
    }
]
```

Quiero crear una tabla donde aparezca los valores de la primera petición, y en caso de que en la segunda petición tengan un valor fijo ponerlos tambien en la tabla.

Seria parecido a esto:

| Id | Valor | Nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 134 |  | Color |
| 134 |  | Talla |
| 134 | LC0314 | Serial |
| 134 | 1.7.3 | Revision |

La tabla la he creado de forma editable con primeng, y ahora mismo ya estoy mostrando los valores de la primera petición, me faltaria incluir relacionar la segunda petición para poder incluirla.

```
                   <p-table [value]="valoresProd" responsiveLayout="scroll" (onEditInit)="onEditInit($event)" (onEditCancel)="onCancelInit($event)"> 
                          <ng-template pTemplate="header"> 
                              <tr> 
                                  <th>Id</th> 
                                  <th>Valor</th> 
                                  <th>Nombre</th> 
                              </tr> 
                          </ng-template> 
                          <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-valoresProd let-rowData> 
                              <tr> 
                                  <td> 
                                      <p-cellEditor> 
                                          <ng-template pTemplate="output"> 
                                              {{rowData.Id}} 
                                          </ng-template> 
                                      </p-cellEditor> 
                                  </td> 
                                   <td pEditableColumn > 
                                      <p-cellEditor> 
                                        <ng-template pTemplate="input"> 
                                          <input pInputText  type="text [(ngModel)]="VALORFIJO" name="author"> 
                                        </ng-template> 
                                        <ng-template pTemplate="output"> 
                                           VALORFIJO 
                                        </ng-template> 
                                       </p-cellEditor> 
                                    </td> 

                                  <td>
                                    <p-cellEditor>
                                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                            {{ rowData.Nombre}}
                                        </ng-template>
                                    </p-cellEditor>
                                </td>
                              </tr> 
                          </ng-template> 
                      </p-table>
```

La respuesta de la API no la puedo tocar, por lo tanto para relacionar tengo que usar el campo Nombre.

Gracias.

Comment: No veo cual es el problema... no puedes tocar la API pero siempre puedes hacer un objeto nuevo en angular juntando ambos. Simplemente recorres el segundo objeto y buscas en el primero los atributos que coincidan con el nombre que estás buscando y le añades el valor "extra". Así cuando le pases los datos a la tabla ya irá todo junto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es algo parecido a un `left join`. Para estos recorres el primer array (por ejemplo usando la función `map`), en cada iteración buscan en el segundo array el item que se parea según el criterio, que en tu caso es `IdCampo === Nombre`

```js
const array1 = [
    {
      "Nombre": "Color",
      "IdProd": 134,
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Talla",
      "Id": 134,
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Revision",
      "Id": 134,
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Serial",
      "Id": 134,
    }
];
const array2 =[
    {
      "IdCampo": "Serial",
      "ValorFijo": "LC0314",
    },
    {
      "IdCampo": "Revision",
      "ValorFijo": "1.7.3",
    }
];


const join = array1.map( a=> {
  const valorFijo = array2.find(b=>b.IdCampo === a.Nombre)?.ValorFijo;
  return valorFijo ? {...a,ValorFijo:valorFijo } : a;
});

//const join = array1.map( a=> ({ ...a, ValorFijo :  array2.find(b=>b.IdCampo === a.Nombre)?.ValorFijo}));

console.log(join)
```

Comment: Genial, me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias!